# Why some Azerite powered gear cannot be sold to vendors?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The title pretty much says it.

I've got some items dropped by elite mobs (those that appear with a big star on the mini map), which are *Rare* and have *Azerite powers*, but are lower item level than what I have currently equipped. Some of them can be sold to vendors for gold, some of them are marked with *"No sell price"*.

Why is that? Am I missing something if I simply delete those items? Should I keep them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is speculated that azerite gear lost its gold value when patch 8.1 dropped to ensure players would scrap it instead of vendoring it. As of patch 8.1, scrapping azerite gear greater than or equal to item level 370 rewards you with [titan residuum](https://www.wowhead.com/currency=1718/titan-residuum), a currency you can use to buy high level azerite gear.  If you are interested in M+ or raid progression, the titan residuum from scrapping pieces of azerite gear should be far more valuable than 50 or so gold.

I imagine this helped the support team avoid a large number of tickets requesting residuum for mistakenly vendored azerite gear.

If you no longer need a piece of azerite gear, feed it to the scrapper. There's no need to hang on to it.